# NC: Can a subcontractor place a lien on a property if the amount is less than $500?

Tags: north-carolina, debt

In NC, can a subcontractor place a mechanic's lien on a property if the amount is less than $500?

Answer (score 1):

The NC lien law is [here](http://www.ncleg.net/EnactedLegislation/Statutes/HTML/ByChapter/Chapter_44A.html). Whether one is the initial contractor or a subcontractor, there is no minimum threshold for filing a claim. 44A-8 says that

> Any person who performs or furnishes labor or professional design or
>   surveying services or furnishes materials or furnishes rental
>   equipment *pursuant to a contract, either express or implied, with the
>   owner of real property* for the making of an improvement thereon
>   shall, upon complying with the provisions of this Article, have a
>   right to file a claim of lien on real property on the real property to
>   secure payment of all debts owing for labor done or professional
>   design or surveying services or material furnished or equipment rented
>   pursuant to the contract.

A subcontractor has a contract with a contractor, not the property owner.  44A-18(a) says

> A first tier subcontractor who furnished labor, materials, or rental
>   equipment at the site of the improvement shall have a *lien upon funds*
>   that are owed to the contractor with whom the first tier subcontractor
>   dealt and that arise out of the improvement on which the first tier
>   subcontractor worked or furnished materials.

That clause means that a subcontractor has a lien on the funds, not the property. 44A-20(d) is the special clause that opens the door wider, since

> If the obligor is an owner of the property being improved, the lien
>   claimant shall be entitled to a claim of lien upon real property upon
>   the interest of the obligor in the real property to the extent of the
>   owner's personal liability under subsection (b) of this
>   section...which claim of lien on real property shall be entitled to
>   the same priorities and subject to the same filing requirements and
>   periods of limitation applicable to the contractor.

(An obligor is defined as "An owner, contractor, or subcontractor in any tier who owes money to another as a result of the other's partial or total performance of a contract to improve real property").